# AngularJS code completion in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, angularjs, code-completion

I'm starting to learn AngularJS - I used to work in Eclipse on some projects, so I thought I'd keep my IDE and went on to install AngularJS Eclipse plugin:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse

I've created a project and converted it to AngularJS project. When I write angular attributes like **ng-app** it shows bold and blue like Eclipse understands this attribute, but I still don't get any code completion when I start typing "ng-" and every ng attribute shows a warning Undefined attribute name.

Is there something I did wrong? How do I teach my Eclipse to work with AngularJS properly?

Comment: I'm not familiar ith the Eclipse-Angularjs ecosystem, but Ive had good luck using Intellij

Comment: Have you some trace in the "Error Log"  or "Problem" View? I'm using Luna to develop AngularJS Eclipse, so I suggest you to use Luna.